# If an application has a gtk3 backend, should it be enabled for 11.10?

Tags: gtk, packaging, 11.10

If an application has a gtk3 backend and a gtk2 backend, should the package maintainer compile it with the gtk3 backend or can he/she decide which backend to use?

Can I file a bug if an application has a gtk3 backend but is compiled with the gtk2 backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ 2 will still be available in 11.10. So it really should be left to the package maintainer's discretion. If the GTK+ 3 version is deemed stable enough, then it would probably be a good idea to enable it. As far as I know, the goal is to have all applications in the default install ported to GTK+ 3 in time for the 12.04 LTS release. Though GTK+ 2 will probably remain in universe for quite some time.

Some of this work can be tracked on the Desktop Team's [Release Status wiki page.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopTeam/ReleaseStatus)